# Ant - If condition - reading from external array/file and compare it with first arg

Tags: java, ant

I am trying to use ant to build structure regarding to various conditions.
I want to act for all countries in the earth and continent according to which continent they belong

```
<if>
      <or>
          <equals arg1="${country}" arg2="US" />
          <equals arg1="${country}" arg2="CA" />
       </or>
    <then>
        <!-- do stuff -->
    </then>
    <elseif>
        <or>
          <equals arg1="${country}" arg2="DE" />
          <equals arg1="${country}" arg2="AT" />
          <equals arg1="${country}" arg2="FR" />
          <equals arg1="${country}" arg2="NL" />
          <equals arg1="${country}" arg2="SE" />
          <equals arg1="${country}" arg2="ES" />
          ..
       </or>
    <then>
        <!-- do stuff -->
    </then>
    </elseif>
    <elseif>
        <or>
          <equals arg1="${country}" arg2="JP" />
          <equals arg1="${country}" arg2="KR" />
          <equals arg1="${country}" arg2="AU" />
          <equals arg1="${country}" arg2="SA" />
          <equals arg1="${country}" arg2="PL" />
          <equals arg1="${country}" arg2="CN" />
          ..
       </or>
    <then>
        <!-- do stuff -->
    </then>
    </elseif>
</if>
```

Now if you can imagine that there is more than 200 countries + I want to use NOT, AND , and OR conditions also for languages that will lead to very huge file which will be very difficult to modify and maintain later.
Is there way to minimize the code by sorting all countries as array or list in file and letting ant read from this file. 
External file:

```
North_America=["US","CA"]
Europe=["DE","GB","FR",...]
Asia=["JP","PL","CN",..]
AFRICA=[..]
South_America[..]
```

Then it will be very simple to use ant like this:

```
<if>
      <equals arg1="${country}" arg2="${North_America}" />
    <then>
        <!-- do stuff -->
    </then>
    <elseif>
          <equals arg1="${country}" arg2="${Asia}" />
    <then>
        <!-- do stuff -->
    </then>
    </elseif>
    <elseif>
        <equals arg1="${country}" arg2="${Africa}" />
    <then>
        <!-- do stuff -->
    </then>
    </elseif>
..
</if>
```

My problem Not how to load or read properties file in ant but how to read value from array or list

```
<equals arg1="${country}" arg2="${Asia}" />
```

Where "Asia" is array (or list) and the question if that possible to make it in ant to achieve the IF condition like this if first arg equals any value of that array? Or even if there better way to achieve this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ant properties are always strings, so there's no way to truly store or read arrays (or any other type of object).

Fortunately for your issue, country abbreviations always come in the form of unique 2-letter strings, so simply reading them from a comma delimited list stored as one long string can be done easily and reliably.

I recommend ditching ant-contrib completely, if at all possible. Sometimes you'll have a script that requires a `for` loop and there's really no other way around it, but if you're just dealing with a bunch of conditionals, it's better practice to use native Ant. I can elaborate on this further if you're curious.

Regarding the question of whether the country information should be grouped in your build script or a properties file, it's just a matter of choice. I personally prefer to store data in properties files, leaving only logic inside the script itself.

> continents.properties

```
continent_southAmerica=AR,BR
continent_NorthAmerica=US,CA
continent_Asia=PL,SY,JP,SA,CN
continent_Africa=EG,TU,SU,MR,Ly
continent_Europe=FR,Nl,DE,DK,GB
```

> build.xml

```
<fail message="Please specify a country. (-Dcountry=US)">
    <condition>
        <not>
            <isset property="country" />
        </not>
    </condition>
</fail>

<property file="continents.properties" />

<target
    name="build"
    depends="
        north-america-stuff,
        south-america-stuff,
        asia-stuff,
        africa-stuff,
        europe-stuff"
>
    <echo message="Build complete for ${country}, ${continent}." />
</target>

<target name="init-continent">
    <condition property="continent.is.north.america">
        <contains string="${continent_NorthAmerica}" substring="${country}" />
    </condition>

    <condition property="continent.is.south.america">
        <contains string="${continent_SouthAmerica}" substring="${country}" />
    </condition>

    <condition property="continent.is.asia">
        <contains string="${continent_Asia}" substring="${country}" />
    </condition>

    <condition property="continent.is.africa">
        <contains string="${continent_Africa}" substring="${country}" />
    </condition>

    <condition property="continent.is.europe">
        <contains string="${continent_Europe}" substring="${country}" />
    </condition>
</target>

<target name="north-america-stuff" if="continent.is.north.america" depends="init-continent">
    <property name="continent" value="North America" />

    <echo message="Continent: ${continent}" />
</target>

<target name="south-america-stuff" if="continent.is.south.america" depends="init-continent">
    <property name="continent" value="South America" />

    <echo message="Continent: ${continent}" />
</target>

<target name="asia-stuff" if="continent.is.asia" depends="init-continent">
    <property name="continent" value="Asia" />

    <echo message="Continent: ${continent}" />
</target>

<target name="africa-stuff" if="continent.is.africa" depends="init-continent">
    <property name="continent" value="Africa" />

    <echo message="Continent: ${continent}" />
</target>

<target name="europe-stuff" if="continent.is.europe" depends="init-continent">
    <property name="continent" value="Europe" />

    <echo message="Continent: ${continent}" />
</target>
```

Comment: Thanks @CAustin very useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well after asking and rethinking I found the best is to create new properties file and add the value in it the load that properties file in ant script.
also instead of using "equals arg" condition I used "Contains substring"

continent.properties file

```
continent_southAmerica="AR", "BR"...
continent_NorthAmerica="US", "CA"
continent_Asia="PL", "SY", "JP", "SA", "CN",....
continent_Africa="EG", "TU", "SU", "MR", "Ly",....
continent_Europe="FR", "Nl", "DE", "DK", "GB",....
```

Ant script

```
  <!-- load continent.properties file -->
    <loadproperties srcfile="../${continent.properties}" encoding="UTF-8">
        <filterchain>
            <escapeunicode />
        </filterchain>
    </loadproperties>

  <if>
      <contains string="${continent_southAmerica}" substring="${country}" />
    <then>
        <!-- do stuff -->
    </then>
    <elseif>
          <contains string="${continent_Asia}" substring="${country}" />
    <then>
        <!-- do stuff -->
    </then>
    </elseif>
    <elseif>
        <contains string="${continent_Europe}" substring="${country}" />
    <then>
        <!-- do stuff -->
    </then>
    </elseif>
     ..
  </if>
```